# How to fix 'undefined index' and 'some data has already send to the pdf file'

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I want to retrieve the data from database into 'pdf' file but i am getting these errors while executing the code

> Notice: Undefined index: id in
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

I used `isset` function but it is not giving the appropriate output

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');  

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','usr','pass','db');  

$pdf = new FPDF();  
$pdf->AliasNbPages();  
$pdf->AddPage();  
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);  

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {  
    $query = mysqli_query(
        $conn,
        "select * from print where id = '".$_GET['id']."' "
    );  

    while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))  
    {  
        $pdf->Cell(65);  
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,$data['Id'],1,0,'C');  
        $pdf->Cell(40,10,$data['name'],1,1,'C');  
    }  

    $pdf->Output();  
}
?>
```

Comment: you're open to SQL injection and shoudl resolve immediately

Comment: _“I used isset function but it is not giving the appropriate output”_ - isset does not magically provide a value that isn’t there to begin with, it only helps you check if a variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

As it says, `id` (as get parameter) is not defined. You need to call your script as `yourscript.php?id=XX`

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

This means, that you can't send HTTP headers (FPDF sends them in `$pdf->Output()`), because your script has already sent some data (It sends `Notice: Undefined index: id in`)